# Issue with [Accessing a Service without a selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#service-no-selector-access)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have applied below k8s yaml file,

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376

---
apiVersion: discovery.k8s.io/v1
kind: EndpointSlice
metadata:
  name: my-service-1 # by convention, use the name of the Service
                     # as a prefix for the name of the EndpointSlice
  labels:
    # You should set the "kubernetes.io/service-name" label.
    # Set its value to match the name of the Service
    kubernetes.io/service-name: my-service
addressType: IPv4
ports:
  - name: '' # empty because port 9376 is not assigned as a well-known
             # port (by IANA)
    appProtocol: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 9376
endpoints:
  - addresses:
      - "10.4.5.6" # the IP addresses in this list can appear in any order
      - "10.1.2.3"
```

source: [service-no-selector-access](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#service-no-selector-access)

> Note: The Kubernetes API server does not allow proxying to endpoints that are not mapped to pods. Actions such as `kubectl proxy <service-name>` where the service has no selector will fail due to this constraint. This prevents the Kubernetes API server from being used as a proxy to endpoints the caller may not be authorized to access.

I followed this [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) to create service without selector and ran `k proxy my-service` command which should fail according to above quote but it is not failing in my case. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Remove the `name:' '` and try again.

Comment: Have you tried the after removing `name:' '`

Comment: Yes and that doesn't work.